# Developing with SQL Server Express and delpoiyng with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I'am developing a web application with VS2010 Entity Framework and SQL Server Express.

This application will be deploiyed in a server with SQL Server 2008 (not express)

It is possible?

What changes (if needed) i need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

You just need to change your connectionstring to point to the new database.

SQL Express has some limitations to do with performance and scalability (SQL Server Express supports 1 physical processor, 1 GB memory, and 4 GB storage(10GB in 2010 version)) but none in terms of how you utilise it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you develop in SQL Express should work (See @geoff's recommendation). If you need features in SQLServer 2008 that are not available in express, you won't be able to test them.